# Pretty URL getting redirected to query part

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am using .htaccess for URL rewriting. I have used code like:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)$ index.php?page=d/ctg/item&itmctgals=$1 [QSA]
```

and URL is `smstongue.com/friendship-sms` (the alias URL) but it is showing URL with query part in URL i.e. `smstongue.com/?page=d/ctg/browse&itmctgals=friendship-sms`

But I want to show URL like `smstongue.com/friendship-sms` in browser URL bar.
How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly,

do this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} itmctgals=([\w\d-]+) [Nc]
RewriteRule ^ %1/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^([\w\d-]+)$ index.php?page=d/ctg/item&itmctgals=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Thanks. On my earlier host it was working fine the rule which I was using but not on new host. Now, I have few more URLs to rewrite in same .htaccess file. Do I need to write it all for every rule? Also, my rule was just of 1 line, please tell me why it is not working with new host.

Comment: @Kunal Its because of the trailing slash problem. You better re-write others as well. _And don't forget to accept the answer so that this Q/A will be closed_.